# Pentaho PDI: row listener for remote transformations

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pdi, pentaho-data-integration

I already know how to implement a Row Listener for a local transformation using Java (http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Executing+a+PDI+transformation).

Since not the Spoon UI nor the Carte API provide any mechanism for continuous preview of data running on a remote slave, I've tried implementing the same mechanism using plain Java.
However, no available method seems to return a `StepInterface` when attaching to a `SlaveServer` object:

```
KettleEnvironment.init();
SlaveServer ss = new SlaveServer("java", "192.168.200.63", "23346", "cluster", "cluster");
SlaveServerTransStatus state = ss.getTransStatus(transMetaName, carteObjectId, 0);
```

Is there any way of getting a `StepInterface` reference for a remote Carte server in order to attach a row listener ?

If not, is there any way of having a preview of all rows for remote transformations running on a Carte server ?